# Representing insertion of a already created object

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

I'm modeling a sequence diagram from a code like this:

```
void MyObject::createADevice{
   Device* someDevice = new Device();
   devices[i] = someDevice;
   Screen* scr = new Screen();
   someDevice->addScreen(scr);
   ...
}
```

This is the code that I have doubts. I'm modelling with no problem until the call of `someDevice->addScreen()`. I've created a self message with object creation for Device and Screen objects. But I'm failing to represent the last line. How can I do that?

P.S: I'm using Enterprise Architect

Answer (score 0):

The Device and Screen objects needs their own lifelines.  The new operator can be represented as messages to the Device and Screen.  Then addScreen is a message to the Device.

Comment: I did this. I'm worried because there isn't any message between Device and Screen. Screen object is effectively inserted inside addScreen. And I think this needs to be showned.

Comment: Your code also doesn't have a message between device and screen.  The message is from MyObject to Device.